# How to SetParent window but not affect the coordinate?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm using following code to create window control,

```
m_hWnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,
        pszClassName, 0,
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_POPUP, 
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        parenthwnd,
        NULL,
        hInst,
        NULL);
```

then I can move the control to a specified location on the screen as expected:

```
MoveWindow(m_hWnd,x, y,width, height, SWP_NOZORDER);
```

however when the parent window's changed, is there a way to reassign `parenthwnd of m_hwnd`?

I tried using `SetParent` function, but now **MoveWindow** not working with [x,y] in screen coordinates but are coordinates in `parenthwnd`

Comment: Yes, coordinates of a child window are always relative to their parent.  What's your question?

Comment: Are you talking about the parent or the owner? Because in this code `parenthwnd` is the owner of the window, which is not a child window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A child window's position is relative to its parent window, not the screen. If the parent window moves, its child window's move with it.

If you want to move a given child window to a given screen coordinate, use `ScreenToClient()` or `MapWindowPoints()` to convert the screen coordinate into a client coordinate relative to the parent window, and then move the child window to that coordinate.